# How to use local capacitor plugin in android or ios project?

Tags: maven, google-maps, ionic-framework, plugins, capacitor

I added new features in capacitor plugin. so I was gonna check my work through connecting to android project.

this is what I did.

1. In my Android project, I navigated to the android/app directory.
2. Inside the dependencies block of the build.gradle file, I added a reference to local plugin.
   `implementation project(':local-plugin-name')`
3. After adding the dependency, I synchronized the Android project with Gradle.

but I got error. please let me know how can I fix.

if I can't do, I'd like to know how to publish android plugin in moven.

Comment: what error are you talking about? ... please add your code to your question